# Why cant I say variable.array in this case?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors

I don't see why I cant do this, without getting an error saying "Songs cannot be resolved or is not a field". I am a noob by the way, trying to learn this stuff :) Thanks in advance for you time, and please tell me if you need more information.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Band {

public String bandName;
public ArrayList<String> musician = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

// Constructor
 public Band(String bandName) {
    this.bandName = bandName;
 }

 public void getBandSongs(String bandName){
    for (String s : bandName.songs) {             <<<<<<<<<<<ERROR HERE
        String rating = s.substring(0,1);
        s = s.substring(1);
        System.out.println("Rating: " + rating + " - Song name: " + s);
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: I advise you to go through a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: `bandName` is a `String` variable. A `String` variable doesn't have a `songs` member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the errors that the IDE gives you are misleading, but this one is quite clear. 
So, let's analyse it:

**"Songs cannot be resolved or is not a field"**

So that should ring up an alarm. First thing you should do is look at the **type** that is your variable bandName.

```
public void getBandSongs(String bandName){
      for (String s : bandName.songs) ...
```

It's a *String*! Of course you won't be able to access a field "songs" of a type String.

Maybe in your method signature you meant to have the following:

```
public void getBandSongs(Band band)
```

In that case, you should be able to access `band.songs` just fine.

Or you could have meant the following:

```
for (String s : this.songs)
```

That means you would be accessing the "songs" variable of the object instantiation of the class Band.

In summary:

The attributes that you define in your class:

```
public String bandName;
public ArrayList<String> musician = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
```

can be accessed through a variable that is of type of that class (in this case Band).

Hope this has made it a bit clear. Are you following any book in particular? I recommend the O'Reilly series. Good luck!

ps: I don't want to add too much since you are starting. But I advise you to read up on "encapsulation". That means that, unless strictly necessary, your should, by default, make your class's arguments **private** and let other classes access them through "getters" and "setters". Such that:

```
public class Band {

private String bandName;
private ArrayList<String> musician = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

public String getBandName(){
   return this.bandName;
}

public void setBandName(String bandName){
   this.bandName = bandName;
}

//And like that for the other two attributes. That way the classes that need access
// to these will either use a "get" method or a "set" method without directly 
// accessing the attributes. 

}
```

The work of creating getters and setters is so redundant that both [Eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IRjWH-P5pI&noredirect=1) and [Netbeans](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Frp3yr2dag4) IDEs have a functionality that allows you to do these automatically.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a lot in understanding.. I just started at an introductory programming course, and im following the book Big Java Early Objects. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

`songs` is a part of `Band`, not `bandName`.

use `this.songs` instead (or just `songs`).

It should be noted though that public fields are against encapsulation (and thus OOP). Is this really what you want?

The major benefit of encapsulation (providing getters & setters for instance members) is to have a unified way of accessing your fields in a class. This allows you to, for example, add validation logic to your data.

```
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();

public List<String> getSongs(){
    return songs;
}

public List<String> setSongs(List<String> songlist) {
    this.songs = songlist;
}
```

Now you can add validation to these methods. For example if you want to make sure you can only set the songlist if it has at least 5 songs in it:

```
public List<String> setSongs(List<String> songlist) {
    if(songlist.size() > 5) {
        this.songs = songlist;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by public fields are agains encapsulation? Should I use private instead? If I do so, my program doesnt work. This is a assignment I have to make for tomorrow, so I apreciate your quick help already. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should make them private. Then you can access them trough a method that just sets/gets the field. I'll edit my post with a quick example.